# Routing in ASP.NET MVC(Linked tables)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have Interview and Interwier

When I create interview I need to generate link in View and send it to interwier.

So if Interview_id is `=5` Interviewer  will be interviewed with interview id=5

Table Intervier is linked with Interview table

Here is Interviewer table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Interwiers] (
[Interwier_id] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[FIO]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Email]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Telephone]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Birthday]     DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[City]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Salary]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[English]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Interview_Id] INT            NULL,
[Status]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Interwier_id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Interwiers_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([Interview_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Interviews] ([Interview_Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now I generate link like this `http://localhost:51542/Interwier/Welcome` and I need smth like this 'http://localhost:51542/Interwier/Welcome/5' so if Interwier fill data in table  in `Interview_Id` automatically will be id=5 for example.

How I can realize this?

Maybe I don't clearly write my question. If no, tell me that not clearly, I will edit it

**UPDATE**

Here is controller for Interwier, here I write data to table

```
 public ActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Interwier/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Welcome([Bind(Include = "Id,FIO,Email,Telephone,Birthday,City,English,Salary")] Interwier interwierModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.InterwierModels.Add(interwierModel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("WebCamCheck");
        }

        return View(interwierModel);
    }
```

**UPDATE2**

I try to write logic

Here is start screen, here i create Interview (Select Vacancy and write Details about Interview), so I create Interwiev id. It's done.

[image]

After that I create questions and add them to interview, then I click next and questions adding to table with linking to Interview_id

Here is mockup

[image]

After that I need to send invitations to people. There is next mockup

[image]

In Link I need to generate Link to interview , not it like I wrote before.

I need to generate it with id. So then User open it and fill info about him it will be linked to this Interview ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Your are using Entity framework to save data then it is so essay to do this

Let suppose Interwiers tabel has only 2 columns Like Id and name=

```
DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities();
Interwiers  objInterwiers  = new Interwiers();
objInterwiers.Email = "aman@gmail.com";
db.Interwiers.Add(objInterwiers);
db.SaveChanges();
```

now you have no need to enter id field here if you set it auto increment in your table.

After save data you can get you id like:

```
var id = objInterwiers.Id;
```

which was recently added.

and you this to redirect you want

```
return Redirect("/Interwier/Welcome/"+id);
```

whole code in controller will be like:

```
public ActionResult TestSaveData()
{
    DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities(); // your entity name
    Interwiers  objInterwiers  = new Interwiers(); //table name
    objInterwiers.Email = aman@gmail.com;
    db.Interwiers.Add(objInterwiers);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("/Interwier/Welcome/"+id);
}
```

Comment: I already save Interwier. I need other, when I create Interview I have Interview _id. I need to  generate link to interview with interview id. Send it to interwier and he will fill data about him and in interview id in table will be id of interview that he is passing.

Comment: Is the id filled by user and your table id  same where you want to redirect?

Comment: Nope. I make interview, and id filled in interview table. Then via js on View I generate link.
`$("#mybutton").click(function () {
            $("#link").val(document.location.origin+'@Url.Action("Welcome", "Interwier")');
        });`

Comment: After saving/geting Id you can keep id into Viewbag etc and set it with link  Like

$("#link").val(document.location.origin+'@Url.Action("Welcom‌​e", "Interwier",@Viewbag.Id )'); });

Comment: Yes i have seen your latest update it is simple way to keep id within Viewbag or tempdata after creating it and use it where you are creating link like my upper comment.

Comment: Okay, so I understood with link generation. But when user goes to this link and fill data about him, I need to write id to his table in Interview_id row, How I need to do this, correctly? Get this id, from link?

Comment: Yes you are right get id from link. You can use javascript url split function if using ajax or in controller side this is also possible.

Comment: Good & Tick my answer as accepted when done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The default route value is set as {controller}/{action}/{id}.
When generating the links you can use routeValues to set the id. 
for example. if the link is generated from a controller action, then

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
 //code
 Return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Interview", new{InterviewId = Interview.InterviewId});

}
```

This will result in the URL localhost:[portNumber]/Interview/Welcome/InterviewId